Exclude Rounding from Ceiling/Floor Formula in Flow
I have a formula in flow to calculate our term based off the contract start and end dates. The term field is a whole number field with no decimals. If the value calculated is greater than 15 days then I need to take to ceiling value. However, the term value is being calculated with decimal value rounding the value up making the term off by one month.
Example
Contract Start Date: 5/1/2024
Contract End Date: 12/31/2027
Calculates to 1339 Days
365/12 = 30.42
1339 Days/30.42 = 44.02
Because the value calculated as 44.02 with a decimal the formula is taking the ceiling and calculating the term as 45 months when we are expecting 44 months.
I am trying to determine how to not round with a decimal.
Formula:
IF(
    {!$Record.Contract_End_Date__c} >= {!$Record.Contract_Renewal_Date__c},
    IF(
        OR(
            DAY({!$Record.Contract_End_Date__c}) - DAY({!$Record.Contract_Renewal_Date__c}) / (365/12) > 15,
            DAY({!$Record.Contract_End_Date__c}) - DAY({!$Record.Contract_Renewal_Date__c}) <= 30
        ),
        CEILING(({!$Record.Contract_End_Date__c} - {!$Record.Contract_Renewal_Date__c}) / (365/12)),
        FLOOR(({!$Record.Contract_End_Date__c} - {!$Record.Contract_Renewal_Date__c}) / (365/12))
    ),
    1
)


Well, the formula appears to match the requirement that you've laid out (other than it taking the ceiling for greater than 15 average months rather than days). Was that just a copy/paste mistake in your formula, or is there a difference/discrepancy in the requirements you're working with?

If the days calculated in a month is greater than 15 then yes they want the month to be rounded up. For example if the days in the month is say 16 days then round up to the next month. If the days in the month is 13 then round down the month.

My point was that your OR() is saying greater than 15 months instead of greater than 15 days. 44 months is greater than 15 months, which is why your formula is taking the ceiling instead of the floor. I was probing to see if you really meant for that part of your formula to be working on months.
